# Java EE with Glassfish

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I've been writing Java for about 3 years but mostly with SE. Now I'll start Java EE on GlassFish for a project of a reporting tool.

This is my goal to learn Java EE. But I am not sure where to start? What technologies (for beginners) do I need to follow.

Can you recommend me some references to follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could suggest [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) for a start, there is overview of all basic technologies. Then you can google for some specific implementations like Jersey for REST. Eclipselink for JPA, CDI.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You may also like to have a look on:

- JSf or Spring (Frameworks)
- Java persistance API
- Java messaging Service

I dont know whether the last two technologies are supported in J2EE or not, but they are supported in JavaEE6.
A good overview about the these is offered by this book: [JavaEE6 Tutorial](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137081855)

For java persistance API, You may want to look at this book: [Pro JPA 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219564)